# MacBook Air A1466 Model не запускается OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos

Macbook Air ни в какую не хочет запускаться. Произошло это после того как я (сам не понимаю зачем) изменил права доступа ко всем файлам и папкам на диске на "только чтение" для пользователя "система" и для пары групп "wheel" и "stuff". Изменил не через терминал, а в окне свойства папок диска OS X.

Права для моей учетной записи (mac01), под которой я работаю, были и остались полными, ко всем файлам на диске.

В качестве решения, я запустил мак в режиме Single-User и ввел следующие команды:

```
fsck -f
mount -uw /
chmod -R ugo+rwx /
```

Проверка диска не выдала никаких ошибок. Далее всё прошло также без ошибок.

Но это не помогло, как и многочисленные советы из сети (безопасный режим, загрузка с диагностикой системы и тп). Проверка диска, исправление прав доступа утилитой из режима восстановления – также не привели к результату. Загрузка по прежнему зависает где-то на 55% (на экране с лого Apple и прогресс-баром).

Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным, то очень прошу помочь. В сервисе (неофициальном) сказали, что возможно проблема с жёстким диском и придётся его менять. В общем не смогли ни чем помочь.

Но, так как проблема началась после того, как я что-то намудрил с правами доступа, то меня наводит на мысль, что всё дело в программной части а не в аппаратной. Данные, которые хранятся на диске очень важны. Знаю как их перенести на внешний накопитель, но не хотелось бы ставить систему с нуля и затем копировать всё обратно. Поэтому ищется вариант исправления сделанных ошибок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

продублирую свой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484535/178576), данный по поводу другой, но тоже unix-подобной системы (в этом отношении ответ вполне универсален):

---

наиболее эффективный, с моей точки зрения, выход из сложившейся ситуации — сохранение файлов с данными и переустановка системы.

то, что система не загружается в «нормальном» режиме — это лишь самая верхушка «айсберга», остальные последствия будут обнаруживаться позже, в самые, вероятно, неожиданные моменты. из основных «результатов» можно отметить хотя бы пару: во-первых, ваша система сейчас представляет собой «дырявое решето» (с точки зрения безопасности и защищённости системы), во-вторых, некоторые «демоны» могут либо вообще перестать работать (после перезагрузки), либо работать некорректно.

я лично (считая себя далеко не новичком) исправлять последствия такого «вандализма» даже бы не взялся — это адский кропотливый труд.