# Как удалить Apple Git?

Tags: git, apple

Как удалить Apple Git в macOS Sierra располагающийся в **/usr/bin/git** ?

Это так сказать родной Git macOS **git version 2.8.4 (Apple Git-73)**

Я уже делал попытку переименовать папку `/usr/bin/git` командой `sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-apple` , но это не сработало и я получил ответ

> mv: rename /usr/bin/git to /usr/bin/git-apple: Operation not permitted

Есть еще какие-то идеи как удалить Apple Git?

Comment: А зачем удалять системный? можно поставить свой, отдельно в папку и добавить путь с ним в PATH. Если это не подходит, есть более кардинальные и правильные подходы.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448150/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-git-%d0%bd%d0%b0-os-x/576989#576989

Comment: Обновил там ответ.

Comment: Системный мне не нужен. В том то и дело. Я могу поставить другой Git, но зачем мне нужен системный, который занимает место?

Comment: *Operation not permitted* — возможно, тут использован аналог [chattr](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550017/178576), программа [chflags](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chflags.1.html). пример использования именно с этой целью есть тут: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-osx-write-protecting-file-folders-bash-command/

Comment: Системный занимает не столько места, чтобы на нем экономить. Это преждевременная оптимизация.

Answer (score 1):

> Operation not permitted

возможно, тут использован аналог [chattr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550017/178576), программа [chflags](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chflags.1.html).

пример использования именно с этой целью (для защиты файла от изменения) есть [тут](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-osx-write-protecting-file-folders-bash-command/).

---

посмотреть флаги:

```
$ ls -lO /путь/к/файлу
```

сделать файл «системно-незменяемым» (*system immutable*):

```
$ sudo chflags schg /путь/к/файлу
```

обратное действие:

```
$ sudo chflags noschg /путь/к/файлу
```

сделать файл «пользовательски-неизменяемым» (*user immutable*):

```
$ chflags uchg /путь/к/файлу
```

обратное действие:

```
$ chflags nouchg /путь/к/файлу
```

Comment: @NickVolynkin, *зачем?* — ну, например, чтобы «оградить пользователя от [необдуманных действий](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/425111/178576)». кстати, может быть защищён не только отдельный файл, но и весь каталог (`/usr/bin`, применительно к данному вопросу).

Comment: ну да, и айфон тоже водонепроницаемый, чтобы его было удобно ронять из заднего кармана в унитаз. Всё логично. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin отпишитесь пожалуйста если вам удалось этим методом удалить Apple Git.

Comment: я попробовал предложенные команды, но разрешения как были

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  restricted,compressed так и остались такимиже

Comment: @Cyberwatcher я пожалуй не буду пробовать этот метод, потому что у меня работает гораздо менее "хирургический" метод через переменную `$PATH`

Comment: так и я так тоже могу :) а вот интересно как удалить эпловский

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так зачем удалять? просто попробуйте переименовать, предварительно сняв флаг «неизменяемости».

Comment: в том то и дело что флаг неизменяемости снять нельзя ни коим образом, я уже об этом писал, причем делал это даже из под root, все равно флаги не меняются